# Trying to insert a ruby hash into a Postgres Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

I have created this hash from scraped xml data I have retrieved from the web. My next task is to insert this data into a postgresql database where each key is a different column, and I have drawn a blank. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
temp = @ttc.css('vehicle').map do |vehicle|

{
    id: vehicle.attributes["id"].value,
    routeTag: vehicle.attributes["routeTag"].value,
    lat: vehicle.attributes["lat"].value,
    lon: vehicle.attributes["lon"].value
}

end
```

Comment: Postgres provide dedicated datatype for hash i.e. `hstore`.

Comment: if I understand correctly @ttc.css('vehicle') is an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your model name is `Vehicle` and your `vehicles` table has columns named `id`, `routeTag`, `lat`, `lon`, your solution would be as simple as this:

```
@new_vehicle = Vehicle.create(temp)
```